# Determine docker container of incoming request on Unix domain socket

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, docker, unix

I've implemented a small service in Python 2.7 listening on a Unix domain socket. It also retrieves the peer credentials (PID, UID, GID).

Now I'm experimenting with Docker containers and use [volume sharing](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to make the Unix domain socket of this service running on the host visible in the container.

The component in the container sends the requests just fine. But the service should behave differently based on which container the request came from. The peer credentials (PID, UID, GID) of the incoming request are just that from inside the container.

Can I determine from which container the request was sent (without having a separate Unix domain socket for eached container spawned)?

Comment: Is it allowed to send some additional info from the container, or you can't modify the client process behavior? If it is allowed, you may extract the container ID from `/proc/1/cgroup` (in the container) and pass it to your service. The trick is that Docker includes container ID in cgroups' names.

Comment: I could change the 3-party client but I'd prefer not to.

But I also read ["How to know you are inside a Docker container"](https://tuhrig.de/how-to-know-you-are-inside-a-docker-container/) yesterday and this could be an option. I'd rather use /proc/self/cgroup though.

Comment: Thinking about this some more I won't change the client because everything sent by the client must be considered untrusted input.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any EXPOSE here say, EXPOSE 3971 or 3972 which makes it more specific to which container listening on that port request is send to. Apart from checking if SSL is running properly or not, you can also check whether or not you are running the same version of Requests in the container and on the outside.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand your answer. As said in the question it's all about communication via Unix domain socket with peer credentials. No TCP or TLS involved.